# Bot Detect Captcha Set multiple image styles

Tags: c#, captcha

Is there a way to set multiple image style for bot detect captcha?

I am referring to [this](https://captcha.com/doc/aspnet/samples/csharp/asp.net-mvc-jquery-ajax-captcha-sample.html) sample.

I have written an extension class to initialize captcha,

```
public class CaptchaHelper
{
    public static MvcCaptcha GetTicketsCaptcha()
    {
        // create the control instance
        MvcCaptcha myCaptcha = new MvcCaptcha("ExampleCaptcha");
        myCaptchaImageStyle = BotDetect.ImageStyle.AncientMosaic;
     }
}
```

I can set one style, but cannot find a way to set multiple options. Need some help?

Comment: Did you try the "CaptchaRandomization" class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do this, "CaptchaRandomization.GetRandomImageStyle" accepts ImageStyle array.

```
 ImageStyle[] allowedStyles =
        {
            ImageStyle.AncientMosaic, 
            ImageStyle.MeltingHeat,
            ImageStyle.MeltingHeat2,
            ImageStyle.Negative               
        };
 myCaptcha.ImageStyle = CaptchaRandomization.GetRandomImageStyle(allowedStyles);
```

[More details](https://captcha.com/doc/aspnet/examples/csharp/captcha-form-object-settings-example.html)